# Unreachable catch block: Unreachable catch block for InvalidFormatException

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

I am facing problem while reading data from .xlsx file as the catch (InvalidFormatException e) return error for exception as "Unreachable catch block for InvalidFormatException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body"

I have used openxml4j import which I think is necessary

```
public static Object[][] getTestData(String sheetname) {
        FileInputStream file = null;
        try {
            file = new FileInputStream(TEST_DATA_SHEET_PATH);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            book = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It is expected that there should not be error for the InvalidFormatException and data should be red from .xlsx file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
     book = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The code inside this try block, does not throw an `InvalidFormatException`. That is why you are getting the error message.

Perhaps your intention is using that catch block somewhere else.

From the documnetation:

https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create-java.io.File-

This is the methods signiture:

```
public static Workbook create(java.io.File file)
                       throws java.io.IOException,
                       EncryptedDocumentException
```

As you can see above, no `InvalidFormatException`is thrown from this method.

Comment: I am using this code from another source and in that program it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the IDE can't see or understand that a specific ( `InvalidFormatException` ) exception is thrown in a given code segment.
You can simply solve this problem by joining you try blocks:

```
try {
   book = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

with this approach you can also could clean up and join your code like this if your error handling allows it:

```
try {
   file = new FileInputStream(TEST_DATA_SHEET_PATH);
   book = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```